# Get value from select option with jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have problem with getting values from select option when use JQuery UI $('#id').combobox().
When i use simple JQuery without Ui it work but when i use Ui it can't get Value. Here some of my HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Reset by: </td>
        <td>
            <select name="resetType" id="resetType">
                <option value="email" selected>Email</option>
                <option value="phone">Phone's Number</option>
                <option value="username">Username</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="type"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="type"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here my JQuery Code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#resetType').combobox(); // Code have Problem
    switch($('#resetType').val()){
    case 'email':
        $('#type').html('Email: ');
    break;
    case 'phone':
        $('#type').html('Phone: ');
    break;
    case 'username':
        $('#type').html('Username: ');
    break;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did `[name*="type"]` here because you didn't give that textbox an ID or anything, so i'm simply searching for it by `name` attribute.

```
$('#resetType').on('change', function () {
    $('[name*="type"]').val($(this).find('option:selected').val());       
});​
```

Here's a working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/JwB6z/2/

Comment: But when i use `$('#resetType').combobox()` to display JQuery UI my code will error can't get values.

$('#resetType').combobox();
    
$('#resetType').on('change', function () {
        $('[name*="type"]').val($(this).find('option:selected').val());
       
});​